# In System tool kits(STK), it spends too much time to get the access reports of Walker System

Tags: simulation, stk-agi, simulator

I use Matlab2022a and STK11.6 COM connection, I create a Walker system including 100 satelltes and it takes about 10 minutes to obtain access reports between 100 satellites. Is there any way to reduce the time of getting reports? Thanks.

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* How does it scale with N, the number of satellites? If you do 10, 20, 50, 100 does the time scale as $N, N^2, N^3, \exp(N)$...? That may help suggest where to look for speedup. Also, start with a very minimal program that shows the problem. Can you make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ("minimal, complete and verifiable example") and post it here or somewhere? From such a short description it's going to be hard to address your problem. *Thanks!*